# Replacing string contents without using replace or replaceAll

Tags: java, replace

I have a String variable:

```
String str = " abc boy abc funny os abc abcifff abc abc boy abc";
```

I want to replace "abc" as "the", which would result in:

```
the boy the funny os the abcifff the the boy the
```

How can I do this without using `replace` or `replaceAll`?

Comment: Why do you not want to use replaceAll?

Comment: I suspect this may be homework.

Comment: coz if i use replaceAll method it will change everywhere(example:"abc boy abc funny os abc abcifff abc abc boy abc" change as "the boy the funny os the theifff the the boy the").but i need only wherever "abc" ,there only it has to change.

Comment: @shree What have you tried so far? What problems did you run into? Many (most?) of us here would like to see some work on your part, rather than just writing code for you. Unless you're looking to hire a consultant, in which case perhaps you meant to post on http://careers.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: now, don't go voting to close this just because it's simple, you were a beginner too once.

Comment: sorry its not homework..i have requirement like this in my project module

Comment: You probably *can* use `replaceAll` for this, you just need to take into account word breaks and/or white space.

Comment: @Isaac Truett - I think the OP thinks that `replaceAll` just takes a string for the target, and not a regular expression pattern.

Comment: @Rob I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a homework problem or similar, so I'll give you some hints.

(1) Look at the Java [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class

(2) think how to use that in a loop that works like (pseudocode):

```
while there are substrings left to process
    get the next substring in s
    if that is "abc"
       append "the" to the result
    else
       append s to the result
```

Don't forget to handle spaces between the words.

Answer (score 0):

Rules need creative interpretation! Use the Pattern class!

```
Pattern.compile("abc").matcher(yourString).replaceAll("the")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, according to the comments, the prohibition on `replaceAll` is due to misunderstanding, try this:

```
System.out.println(" abc boy abc funny os abc abcifff abc abc boy abc".replaceAll(
            "( ?)abc( +|$)", "$1the$2"));
```

Output:

> the boy the funny os the abcifff the the boy the